# using case statement to assign columnnames

Tags: sql, case

I'm trying to re-write this as a case statement:

```
 SELECT dateadd(day, -@Day, getdate()) AS Dt
    ,COUNT(pkey) AS 'BlockerOut'
  FROM tablename
  WHERE PROJECT='10270' AND RESOLUTION='1'
        AND CREATED>dateadd(day, -(30+@Day), getdate()) AND CREATED<dateadd(day, -@Day, getdate())
        AND PRIORITY='1' AND (DATEDIFF(hour, [CREATED], [RESOLUTIONDATE]))>4) t1
JOIN
(SELECT dateadd(day, -@Day, getdate()) AS Dt
    ,COUNT(pkey) AS 'BlockerIn'
FROM jobissue
WHERE PROJECT='10270' AND RESOLUTION='1'
        AND CREATED>dateadd(day, -(30+@Day), getdate()) AND CREATED<dateadd(day, -@Day, getdate())
        AND PRIORITY='1' AND (DATEDIFF(hour, [CREATED], [RESOLUTIONDATE]))<=4) t2
        ON t1.Dt = t2.Dt
```

I've gotten this far and can't work out how to get further than column

```
SELECT dateadd(day, -@Day, getdate()) AS Dt, 
CASE  
WHEN PRIORITY='1' AND (DATEDIFF(hour, [CREATED], [RESOLUTIONDATE]))<=4 then  (pkey)   end  'BlockerIn'
FROM [jobissue] 
WHERE PROJECT='10270' AND RESOLUTION='1'
AND CREATED>dateadd(day, -(30+@Day), getdate()) AND CREATED<dateadd(day, -@Day, getdate())
group by PRIORITY, CREATED, resolutiondate, pkey
```

this works.. but for two columns I get an error:

```
SELECT dateadd(day, -@Day, getdate()) AS Dt, 
CASE  
WHEN PRIORITY='1' AND (DATEDIFF(hour, [CREATED], [RESOLUTIONDATE]))<=4 then  (pkey)   'BlockerIn'
WHEN PRIORITY='2' AND (DATEDIFF(hour, [CREATED], [RESOLUTIONDATE]))>24 then  (pkey)   'CriticalOut'
end
FROM jobissue
WHERE PROJECT='10270' AND RESOLUTION='1'
AND CREATED>dateadd(day, -(30+@Day), getdate()) AND CREATED<dateadd(day, -@Day, getdate())
group by PRIORITY, CREATED, resolutiondate, pkey
```

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
Incorrect syntax near 'BlockerIn'.

I can't work out the syntax for more than one columnname.. help me please?  Thanks.

Comment: You can't name the same column twice, split the case statement over 2 columns.

Comment: Needs a comma afetr all but the last when i.e. after 'BlockerIn'

Comment: thanks @ Tony I tried the comma but it didn't work, @Mike I wasn't sure what you meant by not using the same column twice. I found a workaround, it's messy but it works `SELECT dateadd(day, -@Day, getdate()) AS Dt, CASE WHEN PRIORITY='1' AND (DATEDIFF(hour, [CREATED], [RESOLUTIONDATE]))<=4 then count(pkey) end 'Blockerout'FROM jobissue WHERE PROJECT='10270' AND RESOLUTION='1' ` It gives the result I want but not how I thought it would be done. Any better ideas? And thanks for your answers guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I meant

```
CASE WHEN PRIORITY='1' then  (ID)   END as 'BlockerIn',
CASE WHEN PRIORITY='2' then  (ID)  END  as 'CriticalOut'
```

This would create two columns with the values in.

If you want one column with multiple values you would do

```
CASE WHEN PRIORITY='1' then  'BlockerIn' 
WHEN PRIORITY='2' then  'CriticalOut' END  AS Priority
```

Comment: Thanks @Mike that top one was exactly it!